# XML Validation does not validate features

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd, jaxp

I want to validate XML file against an external XSD description. Here is the `Schema` obejct created from my XSD

```
       private static Schema xmlSchema; 
       try {
            SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
            String FEATURE= "";
           // forbid DOCTYPE
            FEATURE = "http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl";
           factory.setFeature(FEATURE, true);
           xmlSchema = factory.newSchema(new File(XML_XSD_SCHEME));
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
```

Also, I created `validateXMLSchema`  static method which is responsible for validating XML files:

```
public static boolean validateXMLSchema(String xmlPath) {

    if (xmlSchema == null) {
        return false;
    }

    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        URL xmlFileURL = new File(xmlPath).toURI().toURL();

        inputStream = xmlFileURL.openStream();
        SAXSource saxSource = new SAXSource(new InputSource(inputStream));

        Validator validator = xmlSchema.newValidator();

        String FEATURE ="";

        // disallow DOCTYPE
         FEATURE = "http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl";
         validator.setFeature(FEATURE, true);

        //forbid external Entity 
        FEATURE ="http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities";
        validator.setFeature(FEATURE, false);

        //forbid external parameters
        FEATURE ="http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities";

        validator.setFeature(FEATURE, false);

        validator.validate(saxSource);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    } finally {
        try {
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

The problem is,even if I added external entity definition in my XML file `<!DOCTYPE foo [<!ELEMENT foo ANY ><!ENTITY......`, 
`validateXMLSchema` methode returns `true`.
Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you wanted those features to apply to the SAX parser that reads the XML document. Try creating a new `XMLReader` and configuring it explicitly before passing the `SAXSource` to the `Validator`:

```
SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
spf.setNamespaceAware(true);
XMLReader reader = spf.newSAXParser().getXMLReader();

String FEATURE ="";

// disallow DOCTYPE
FEATURE = "http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl";
reader.setFeature(FEATURE, true);

//forbid external Entity 
FEATURE ="http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities";
reader.setFeature(FEATURE, false);

//forbid external parameters
FEATURE ="http://xml.org/sax/features/external-parameter-entities";
reader.setFeature(FEATURE, false);

SAXSource saxSource = new SAXSource(reader, new InputSource(inputStream));

Validator validator = xmlSchema.newValidator();

validator.validate(saxSource);
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the right way to set features using external XSD validation. I still have some difficulties but I am sure this is due to my implementation and JAVA version. Thx a lot